# How to transfer data between two tables with different structures?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to transfer data into the table 2 using the data contain in table 1. The two tables have the following schema :

Table 1 :

```
column A, column B, column C
```

Table 2 :

```
column A, column B, column C, column D, column E
```

The result I want in table 2 is the following :

Table 2 :

`A values of Table 1`, `B values of Table 1`, `C values of Table 1`, `NULL` (for D values), `NULL` (for E values)

Is there an HQL command that can do this job ?

Comment: Have you tried writing an HQL query? In the case you presented, it must be identical to SQL, or at least an SQL identical query will serve as a good starting point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 
SELECT A, B, C, NULL, NULL FROM TABLE1;
```